# Deploy war with two web.xml

Tags: java, glassfish, jetty

For some application was build a war with two web.xml files inside. I want to deploy that application in different servers, on of that being Jetty and other GlassFish for instance. For Jetty I try to deploy in jetty.xml, and I want it to load both web.xml descriptors files. It would be useful at least some tips for that. This question I consider that is a general one and I will not provide a concrete code for it.

Comment: Your .war file has two `WEB-INF/web.xml` entries?

Comment: I think you are wanting to change your build to include either one of these web.xml files  - maybe consider maven copy resources?

Comment: @VGR These two web.xml are in two different directories.

Comment: `WEB-INF/web.xml` is the only one that counts.  The other web.xml is just an XML file in the archive, which a servlet container doesn’t care about.

Comment: Why two web.xml files?  why not use the features of Servlet 3.1 and make one of them a web-fragment?